# Is there a way to apply styles to a parent element when hovering over child?

Tags: html, css

I have a  with a link inside. I want to style said  when I hover over the link.

```
<div class="video">
   <div class="video-interior">
      <a href="#">LINK</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I hover over the 'a' tag I want to apply styles to the outermost div.

Is that possible?

Comment: you need to use jquery for this.

Comment: No, you can't traverse *up* the DOM in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access parent elements [with current CSS implementations](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject).

But you can use the `:hover` pseudo class on the parent element directly, which is the most obvious solution here.

```
.video:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing I could think of but It doesn't work well in IE. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: it depends on the actual context. e.g if the `.video` contains other elements, hovering on other element also trigger this and change the background color, while if we only want hovering ***on the link*** inside to change the background, this won't work expectedly.

Comment: @ToniRomero  "It doesn't work well in IE" This is only true for IE 7 and older. Those browsers have a market share of roughly 0.5%. Besides of that it works perfectly fine in all browsers of the last three years.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the hover to the div which contains the `<a>` tag and this will give the effect you describe:

*CSS :*

```
.video:hover { /* your stylings */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a jQuery example:

```
$(function()
{
   $('.video .video-interior a').on('hover',function()
   {
       $(this).parent().parent().css('background','#f00');
   }
});
```